# Am I using MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather properly?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to perform matrix vector multiplication using MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather. I've seen some of the other code but it doesn't address the specific problem I have.

My attempt is to perform the operation Ax = b, by splitting rows of the matrix between processes and calculate the part of b in every process and gather them together into the b vector at the end. For simplicity I'm assuming the that the dimensions of the number of rows is divisible by the number of processes. Here is my attempt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

void Mat_Vec(int n, int m, double *A, double *x, double **b, int myrank, int p, MPI_Comm comm)
{
    double *local_A, *local_b;
    int local_n;
    int i, j, ii;

    MPI_Bcast(&n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
    MPI_Bcast(&m, 1, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
    MPI_Bcast(x, m, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, comm);

    local_n = n/p;

    local_A = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*m*local_n);
    local_b = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*local_n);

    MPI_Scatter(A, local_n*m, MPI_DOUBLE, local_A,local_n*m, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, comm);

    for (i = 0; i < local_n; i++)
    {
        ii = i*m;
        local_b[i] = 0.0;
        for(j=0; j < m; j++)
            local_b[i] += local_A[ii+j]*x[j];

    }

    MPI_Gather(local_b, local_n, MPI_DOUBLE,(*b), local_n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, comm);

    free(local_A);
    free(local_b);
}

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n, m, p;
    int my_rank;
    int i;

    double *A, *x, *b;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    if (my_rank == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: ")
        n = 4;
        m = 4;
        A = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*n*m);
        x = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*m);
        b = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*n);

        printf("Enter the matrix row wise \n");
        for (i=0; i < n*m; i++)
            A[i] = 1.0;
        printf("Enter the vector\n");
        for (i=0; i < m; i++)
            x[i] = 1.0;
    }

    Mat_Vec(n, m, A, x, &b, my_rank, p, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (my_rank == 0)
    {
        for (i=0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%lf\n", b[i]);
        free(A); free(x); free(b);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The main function has allocated the memory necessary for all the inputs of the matvec function. I keep running into the following error: terminated with signal 11. I believe it has to do with some process trying to access memory that has not been allocated bt I cant see where that would be.

I use the following routine:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mpi_matvec.c
#SBATCH --time=00:02:00
#SBATCH --output=matvec.%j
#SBATCH --ntasks=2

mpirun ./matvec
```

Comment: Is the error in scatter or gather ? Please edit your question with a [MCVE] that shows how your subroutine is invoked. Any reason why you declared `double **b` instead of `double *b` ?

Comment: I  made the edits you asked for. The reason I declared b like that was to be able to change b in memory rather than returning a value from the function. b is where I store my final result. From my debugging the code runs until it hits Gather.

Comment: The root cause is `x` is only allocated on rank `0`. I still do not understand your rationale for using `double **b` but that is not involved in this issue.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much